# Calculate average with sql query

Tags: sql, date, average

I want to know the average hourly wage of each user from month March 2018. I want to calculate this with an SQL query.

I have this kind of data:

[image]

The start date indicates when the hourly wage starts and when there is a new start date that hourly wage applies etc.

The outcome should be:

```
2 €10,65
4 €9,90
```

How can I do this in SQL?

Comment: What is your RDBMS??

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query. Creating a calendar table and then a `cte` to add missing data for missing dates. once we have data for missing dates, simple filter in `WHERE` clause and `GROUPBY` will work.

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #temp

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#calendar') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #calendar;

CREATE TABLE #temp
(
UserId INT,
StartDate DATE,
HourlyWage decimal(10,2)
)

DECLARE @date DATE = '20180305'
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES 
(2,'20180205', 10.3),
(2,@date, 10.3),
(2,DATEADD(DAY,1,@date), 10.3),
(2,DATEADD(DAY,2,@date), 10.3),
(2,DATEADD(DAY,3,@date), 10.3),
(2,DATEADD(DAY,4,@date), 10.3),
(2,DATEADD(DAY,5,@date), 10.3),
(2,DATEADD(DAY,6,@date), 10.3),
(2,DATEADD(DAY,7,@date), 10.3),
(2,DATEADD(DAY,8,@date), 10.3),
(2,DATEADD(DAY,9,@date), 10.3),
(2,DATEADD(DAY,10,@date), 10.3),
(2,DATEADD(DAY,11,@date), 10.3),
(2,DATEADD(DAY,12,@date), 10.3),
(2,DATEADD(DAY,13,@date), 10.3),
(2,DATEADD(DAY,14,@date), 10.3),
(2,DATEADD(DAY,15,@date), 10.3),
(2,DATEADD(DAY,16,@date), 10.3),
(2,DATEADD(DAY,17,@date), 10.3),
(2,DATEADD(DAY,18,@date), 10.3),
(2,DATEADD(DAY,19,@date), 10.3),
(2,DATEADD(DAY,20,@date), 10.3),
(2,DATEADD(DAY,21,@date), 10.3),
(2,DATEADD(DAY,22,@date), 12.5),
(2,DATEADD(DAY,23,@date), 12.5),
(2,DATEADD(DAY,24,@date), 12.5),
(2,DATEADD(DAY,25,@date), 12.5),
(2,DATEADD(DAY,26,@date), 12.5),
(4,'20170221', 9.5),
(4,'20170301', 9.7),
(4,'20180227', 9.9)

DECLARE @FromDate DATETIME ,
        @ToDate DATETIME;

SELECT @FromDate = MIN(StartDate) ,
       @ToDate = MAX(StartDate)
FROM   #Temp;


SELECT   TOP ( DATEDIFF(day, @FromDate, @ToDate) + 1 ) calendarDate = CAST(DATEADD(
                                                                                 DAY ,
                                                                                 number ,
                                                                                 @FromDate) AS DATE) 
INTO     #calendar
FROM     [master].dbo.spt_values
WHERE    [type] = N'P'
ORDER BY number;

;WITH tempCTE
AS ( SELECT  DISTINCT t.userid ,
                      cal.calendarDate
     FROM    (   SELECT   calendarDate
                 FROM     #calendar c
                 ) cal
             CROSS JOIN (   SELECT UserId ,
                                   MIN(StartDate) OVER ( PARTITION BY UserId ) AS Mindate ,
                                   MAX(StartDate) OVER ( PARTITION BY UserId ) AS Maxdate 
                            FROM   #Temp ) t
     WHERE   cal.calendarDate
     BETWEEN t.Mindate AND t.Maxdate )

         SELECT   cal.UserId ,
         AVG(x.HourlyWage ) AS Avg_Wage
FROM     tempCTE cal
         CROSS APPLY (   SELECT   TOP 1 t.HourlyWage
                         FROM     #Temp t
                         WHERE    t.UserId = cal.UserId
                                  AND t.StartDate <= cal.calendarDate
                         ORDER BY t.StartDate DESC ) AS x
WHERE CalendarDate BETWEEN '20180301' AND '20180331' --your date filter here
GROUP BY cal.UserId
```

**Result:**

```
+--------+-----------+
| UserId | Avg_Wage  |
+--------+-----------+
|      2 | 10.654838 |
+--------+-----------+
```

Comment: But what about the first 4 days of March for User 2? They need to have the last set hourly wage. Now I get 10.71 and I want 10.65

Comment: You mean, for missing days in march, previous available day wage must be considered? Can you use a calendar table?

Comment: Exactly, how can I use a calendar table?

Comment: ok. I have updated answer. This should work for all users in the filter date range.

Answer (score 0):

The below query is grouping the all the records for each `userid` and then calculating the average. For grouping, we have used `group by` clause.

Also, the [MONTH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/month-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function returns an integer that represents the month of the specified date. Since you are interested in March, so we are comparing this with 3.

```
Select UserId, avg(HourlyWage) 
from <<table>>
where month(StartDate) = 3
group by UserId
```

Please remember to change the `<<table>>` with actual table name.